# Flowplayer Advertisements and Video Resolution

Tags: video-streaming, flowplayer, ads

I am developing an online streaming and download website and will be using flowplayer (HTML 5) for streaming videos online. My question here is how do i display advertisements at the beginning / end of the video? Another request from the client was to display AD's at the mid-point of the video? Is it possible to do so?

Additionally, is it possible to provide options to change resolutions of the video(just like the ones present on youtube?)